# Gradle JAR add to classpath

Tags: java, gradle, classpath, libraries

I am trying to use a number of external libraries in a Java project. The project runs fine from Intelij but I want to package it in a jar, (or something else) so I can distribute it to others. When I package it in a jar it works if I just do hello world, but as soon as I start using my libraries I get the error bellow. I have also tried packaging it as an application but when I run the batch file it just opens and then immediatly closes a command window. I read all the other posts and nothing is fixing my problem. Please help

[My error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNMrH.png)

[My build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frTtW.png)

Comment: *I have also tried packaging it as an application but when I run the batch file it just opens and then immediatly closes a command window*. Then why not do the same thing as what you would do if you just had a jar: open a command windo, and execute the script that starts the application, in that already opened command window?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely that your classpath does not point to the correct relative location of your 3rd party libraries. You can check the manifest file to verify if the paths are correct.

However, if it is a runnable jar file with a `main` method (which it looks like it is), you should use the [Application plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) and package it with the [Distribution plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/distribution_plugin.html). Right now you are using the [Java Library Distribution plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_distribution_plugin.html), which is for libraries. If you do this, you can remove most of the stuff under your `jar` task.

When testing it locally, run `gradle run` and when ready, use `gradle distZip` to create a zip of it all. It will create a script used to start the application with the correct classpath.

Alternatively, you could also package it in a fat jar using the [Shadow plugin](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/introduction/) or similar.